# Eslint husky and lint staged does not work

Tags: reactjs

I set in my react js application husky:

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "format": "eslint **/*.{js,ts,tsx,jsx} --fix && prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json|css|scss|md|tsx)\"",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,css,scss}": ["npm run format", "git add"]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.12",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

I expect, when i commit to run husky but if i add some changes in my app and after that do a commir, the husky is not running, even with the above settings. How to fix husky setting to make it workable?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for related issue, I was trying to make a pre-commit with husky and lint-staged, then I've found in a tutorial [HERE](https://dev.to/hggonzalezdev/get-started-with-git-hooks-and-husky-2c3e) that husky was change your installation since the release of version 6.

Before

```
npm install --save-dev husky
```

or

```
yarn add --dev husky
```

And config your hooks

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
```

Try to Run

```
npx husky-init && npm install
```

Yarn 1

```
npx husky-init && yarn
```

Yarn 2

```
yarn dlx husky-init --yarn2 && yarn
```

Hope that'll work...